# How to hide custom taxonomy archives same way as hiding custom post types?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives

I'm trying to make it so my custom taxonomy terms don't have archive pages. I achieved something similar for a custom post type using "publicly_queryable'  => false". I tried this from the docs inside the register_taxonomy function:

```
'public' => false,
'rewrite' => false,
```

Which works.. but it also removes the ability to view the taxonomy from anywhere in the dashboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set `public` to false, this taxonomy will get hidden in all places.

So if you want it to be visible in wp-admin, you’ll have to also set `show_ui` to true - it will show the admin interface to manage this taxonomy.

You can see the full list of params here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/

And here is a generator, that may be a nicer way to create code for registering taxonomies/posts:
https://generatewp.com/taxonomy/

Comment: Thank you for this. After posting my question, I realize that "publicly_queryable' => false" actually does work with custom taxonomies.. Do you know how that differs from public -> false and rewrite -> false?

Comment: You can find full explanation of these params in Codex (there’s a link in my answer)

Comment: Thanks, was just wondering if you could provide a better explanation than what's in the Codex. From what I understand, publicly_queryable disables archives, and public -> false & rewrite -> false basically disable it from showing to the public in singular view.

Comment: Not exactly... Publicly queryable disables automatic query variables for that taxonomy. Rewrite disables only nice permalinks (but you can still display lists using query args).